# [SOLVED]Orientation_mode issue

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using ROS-indigo on a VM that run Ubuntu-14.04.5.
I want to store on a file the informations of "/move_base/NavfnROS/plan" (in particular I need the position and orientation), to do so I first run this launch file:

```
<launch>
    
    <!-- Transformations /-->
    
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="static_transform" args="8.5 21.5 0 1.57079633 0 0 map base_link 100"/>
    
    <!-- static Map /-->    
    <node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" name="static_map" args="/home/rob/catkin_ws/src/map_server/maps/testmap1.yaml" />

    <!-- move_base + costmap parameters /-->
    
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" output="screen" >
        <rosparam file="/home/rob/catkin_ws/src/move_base1/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="/home/rob/catkin_ws/src/move_base1/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="/home/rob/catkin_ws/src/move_base1/move_base_config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="/home/rob/catkin_ws/src/move_base1/move_base_config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    </node>
        
</launch>
```

after that I run rviz and use the "2D Nav Goal" button to set a goal in my static_map and let global_planner to generate a path_plan. I finally use `rostopic echo /move_base/NavfnROS/plan >> "filel.txt"` in the terminal to store the information that I need.

When I read the stored information in "file.txt" I correctly obtain the positions, but the orientation shows always `x:0 y:0 z:0 w:1` though i set the "orientation_mode" parameter equal to 1 (FORWARD) in the "costmap_common_params.yaml".

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (And yes, I already build the workspace with catkin_make).

The reference link where i read about the "orientarion filter" http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322608/%5Bsolved%5Dorientation_mode-issue/) by [RobertoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/41349/robertod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem: when I was trying to implement the global planner, I missed this:

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" output="screen" >
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="global_planner/GlobalPlanner" />
...
</node>
```

After that, from rqt_gui->dynamic reconfigure, was simple to change the orientation_mode from *none* to *Forward*

---

Originally posted by [RobertoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/41349/robertod/) with karma: 16 on 2019-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0